# Unable to downgrade python version in macos using Homebrew

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, opencv, homebrew

Facing issues when trying to downgrade python version from 3.7.3 to 3.6.5_1. I have did lot of research before reaching to stackoverflow family and all of them were suggesting the same resolution steps that i have tried as below, but found no luck. I looking for the python 3.6.5_1 version because Python 3.7 is unsupported by Keras/TensorFlow and thus are not a good choice for OpenCV either:

Option 1:

`brew unlink python`

`brew install --ignore-dependencies https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/f2a764ef944b1080be64bd88dca9a1d80130c558/Formula/python.rb`

**Error: Calling Installation of python from a GitHub commit URL is disabled! Use 'brew extract python' to stable tap on GitHub instead.**

Option 2:
`brew switch python 3.6.5`

**Error: python does not have a version "3.6.5" in the Cellar.**

after couple of tries I realized that it is problem with the git url that homebrew has it to get python 3.6.5_1 version and that would have changed or the commit url might not be the latest.

macOS version : Catalina 10.15.6

So seeking your guidance and suggestions on how to solve this problem. Also please let me know if missed any info that is required to post here(which could've helped in solving the problem)

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'd recommend to use [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) instead, it allows you to install multiple different versions of Python at the same time.

Comment: yeah, I recommend use pyenv too, if it is not that disruptive for you.

Comment: Another hacky way is to reset brew commit to the python version that you prefer and download from there.

Comment: I cannot find a tap with version 3.6.5. But if you are ok with most recent 3.6.x version, then this command works fine: `brew install sashkab/python/python@3.6`.

Comment: notice that 'brew switch' is no longer supported. you can use brew unlink and brew link instead.

Answer (score 10):

using `brew install sashkab/python/python@3.6` works. credit to @Jean-Pierre Matsumoto.

Comment: Getting this: ==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Error: No previously deleted formula found.

Answer (score 1):

what has worked for me (of course you can replace 3.7 with any valid python version like 3.5, 3.6, 3.8, 3.9, etc)

```
brew install python@3.7
```

and since brew switch is no longer supported you can simply run

```
brew unlink python3
brew link python@3.7
```

now you can verify python3 version as desired

```
python3 --version
```

you can use link and unlink in the example above to switch versions and/or to setup virtualenvs with specific python versions

```
virtualenv --python=python3.7 PATH_TO_NEW_ENV
```

Comment: to make your new virtualenv accessible to jupyter


#activate your new env by running 
source PATH_TO_ENV/bin/activate


#make sure ipykernel is installed by running
pip install ipykernel


#to make env visible to jupyter as a kernel, run
python -m ipykernel install --user --name=NAME_IN_JUPYTER

#to find your new env, in the upper menu hit Kernel > Change kernel